# Deleting a row from a mariaDB database using python

Tags: python-3.x, mariadb

I am at a complete loss at this point. I have tried many ways to get this to work but I am still having trouble. I am building a simple script to add or delete movies to a mariaDB database. The adding a movie part is easy enough but I am having trouble on the deleting part. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
elif choice == "2":
    print("What movie do you want to remove?")
    remove = input("Movie Title: ")
    del_movie = "DELETE FROM movies WHERE title = '?'"
    cur.execute(del_movie, remove)
    conn.commit()
    print(remove,"has been deleted!")
    print(cur.rowcount, "record(s) deleted")
```

The command goes through and I don't get an error anymore, but when I query the database none of the rows have been deleted.

Comment: Are you sure your command should use single quotes around the `?`?  Often the ORM will quote the variable automatically, so you might be running a perfectly valid command that fails to match any rows because your value isn't what you think it is.  E.g. you might be running `DELETE FROM movies WHERE title = '\'Kill Bill\''` when you meant that value to have single quotes.
Second idea: are your tables/columns case-sensitive?  Usually MySQL isn't case-sensitive, but that can be a gotcha.

Comment: Apparently I need single quotes around the ? because if I don't I get an error saying the syntax isn't right. I thought I wouldn't need single quotes since with the adding a movie command it goes through without a hitch and doesn't use quotes but it is a tuple. Also they are not case-sensitive, found that out earlier this morning.

Comment: You may get more detailed answers if you include the specific ORM that you're using -- is it sqlalchemy or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue, the variable needed to be a tuple format so the command line looks like this now.

```
cur.execute("DELETE FROM movies WHERE title = ?", (remove,))
```